# iOS6 MapKit - Nearby Places

Tags: xcode, ios6, mapkit

In iOS6, what's the class/code do I use to fetch Nearby Places?

I know it's the Map Kit.  I have been looking at tutorials and none of them address the recent MKLocalSearch update that Apple did in January 13'.

Any suggestions for a simple solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tutorial demonstrating the MKLocalSearch:

http://phpadvocate.com/blog/2013/01/ios-6-1-simple-example-using-mklocalsearch/